# calculation with undefined number of rows

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, dbt

I would like to add a calculation taking into account we could have one, two, three or a lot of more rows. We can get all the data using the relations but I am a bit stuck because the number of relation are undefined.
For example, as a source:

```
SELECT 123 AS id
      ,250 AS amount
      ,225 AS debt
      ,NULL AS relation
      ,1 AS rn
UNION ALL    
SELECT 124 AS id
      ,150 AS amount
      ,25 AS debt
      ,123 AS relation
      ,2 AS rn
UNION ALL   
SELECT 125 AS id
      ,160 AS amount
      ,50.25 AS debt
      ,124 AS relation
      ,3 AS rn
UNION ALL
SELECT 126 AS id
      ,80 AS amount
      ,25 AS debt
      ,125 AS relation
      ,4 AS rn
```

**Source Table**

| id | amount | debt | relation | rn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 250 | 225 | NULL | 1 |
| 124 | 150 | 25 | 123 | 2 |
| 125 | 160 | 50.25 | 124 | 3 |
| 126 | 80 | 25 | 125 | 4 |

**End Table**

| id | amount | debt | relation | rn | cal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 250 | 225 | NULL | 1 | 250 |
| 124 | 150 | 25 | 123 | 2 | 22.5 |
| 125 | 160 | 50.25 | 124 | 3 | 7.5375 |
| 126 | 80 | 25 | 125 | 4 | 3.75 |

I would need to apply a calculation like:

- row 1: amount
- row 2: row2.debt*row1.debt/row1.amount
- row 3: row3.debt*row2.debt/row2.amount*row1.debt/row1.amount
- row 4: row4.debt*row3.debt/row3.debt*row2.debt/row2.amount*row1.debt/row1.amount
- etc..

I am using dbt but happy to hear about BigQuery or other SQL as I am really curious how this could be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little math can help here - see below

```
select *,
  ifnull(
    round(exp(sum(ln(debt)) over(order by id rows between unbounded preceding and current row))
    / exp(sum(ln(amount)) over(order by id rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding)), 2),
    amount
  ) cal
from `project.dataset.table`
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Note: I am using `order by id` assuming that `id` column defines order of rows.  You can adjust it as needed

Comment: hi, I have been testing the rows between unbounded preceding (...) and it is really interesting. I know I can use it in other places. Can I know why this doesn't work without the EXP and LN functions? I am trying to understand this as the scenario is a bit deeper than I have posted and I would like to see if I can solve it. I also have 0 and negative values which I have seen in the docs LN doesn't work with them. thank you

Comment: `Can I know why this doesn't work without the EXP and LN functions?` - sure. LN allows you to transform multiplication (of values in rows within set window)  into sum of those values - LN(v1 \* v2 \* ... \* vN) = LN(v1)+LN(v2)+...+LN(vN). And then - using EXP gives you actual multiplication result - EXP(LN(v1\*v2\*... \*vN)) = v1\*v2\*... \*vN. - which is what your calculation formula is :o)